# WMI call to a different domain

Tags: wmi

Is it possible to read registry key of a remote machine which belongs to a different domain using WMI calls?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, only you must ensure to set the credentials of the connection according to the remote machine to access, and then use the  [`StdRegProv`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393664%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) wmi class which allow you to access the registry in local and remote machines. A key point is the namespace where the class is located, that depends of the version of windows installed in the remote machine. so for Windows Server 2003, Windows XP, Windows 2000, Windows NT 4.0, and Windows Me/98/95 the StdRegProv class is available in the root\default namespace and for others versions like windows Vista/7 the namespace is root\CIMV2.  check the accepted answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972352/is-it-possible-to-read-write-the-registry-of-a-remote-machine-with-different-cred) to see a sample.